# Got an error "Checking for program pkg-config : not found" during execution "bitbake image_name"

Tags: build, yocto, bitbake, pkg-config

I want to build the yocto image with some additional layers and additional g-streamer functionality for nunki-PHYboard (IMX6). I have added the meta-freescale layer and accepted for build "gstreamer-imx" module and "imx-codec".

During execution the bitbake build I have got an pkg-config error.
Here is some screenshots:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rquqZ.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFujN.png

`echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
 /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig`

`pkg-config --version 
 0.29.1`

How to avoid this error?

Comment: Maybe ask directly on [meta-freescale](https://github.com/Freescale/meta-freescale/issues) Github issues tracker? It should work properly as [gstreamer1.0-plugins-imx_git.bb](https://github.com/Freescale/meta-freescale/blob/master/recipes-multimedia/gstreamer/gstreamer1.0-plugins-imx_git.bb) already includes `inherit pkgconfig`. Maybe try with more recent version of layer than rocko?

Comment: I have `inherit pkgconfig` too in **gstreamer1.0-1.12.imx.bb**. I am not sure about more recent version, because there are a lot of dependencies between the layers. I have tried to change the branch of meta-freescale (for some other reason) and nothing was worked.

Comment: your gstreamer1.0-plugins-imx is coming from meta-phytec and that recipe does not seem to actually depend on pkgconfig. I'm not familiar with these layers so can't comment on how to fix but you might want to consider using the gstreamer1.0-plugins-imx from meta-freescale (by fixing layer priorities or just asking for the correct version explicitly)

Comment: @jku I have added meta-freescale just for the "imx-codec", because I did not find it in previously installed images. I guess I have to use gstreamer from meta-phytec. But I am not sure(